# Angular: seperate common env variables to commonEnv.ts file

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular project, I have multiple different environment configs to support different countries for which I have created one environment file per config like

- localIn
- stagIn
- prodIn
- localBr
- stagBr
- prodBr
- localAu
- stagAu
- prodAu
- .....

and so on

1. But in all of these files, I have 60% of the variables common i.e value of 60% of the variables is the same in all the files.
2. Rest 30% of the variable's value changes only country-specific i.e. they a variable in India is the same for local, stag and prod, it only changes for Brazil, Australia, and other countries.
3. Now last 10% of the variable's value changes on each file.

I am looking for a solution where I can have something like `commonEnv.ts` file where I can keep all my common environments variables.

Then commonIndia.ts where I can keep all country-specific common variables, like here India specific variables.

And at last individual files for each config which is already seen in Angular.

---

Is it possible to do so in Angular? Please tell me how.

If not, how can I solve my problem?

> Also if we can merge commonEnv.ts, common-contry.ts and config.ts file into single env.ts file on each Angular serve/build would be great.

Comment: if they are common and not environment specific why not move to code. environment files are those which are different for every environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a simple solution ,you can create a `CommonEnv` object and use it as base configuration for other enverment objects

*common-env.ts*

```js
export  const CommonEnv = {
     apiUrl : '127.0.0.1/api',
     production : true
}
```

import the CommonEnv to other environments object like this

*environment.ts*

```
export const environment = {
  ...CommonEnv,
  production : false //  change a proprty value come from CommnEnv
};
```

*environment.prod.ts*

```
export const environment = {
   ...CommonEnv,
   apiUrl : '216.58.206.174/api' //  reset the apiUrl
};
```

Comment: Nice, had that problem ub the past. Didnt think of trick of overriding map key.

Comment: @Antoniossss what do you mean by map key 

Comment: setting object prop twice - will result in overriding first one. JS objects are maps.

Comment: yes that's exactly what happened and it 's look like this without the spread operator `const environment = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, CommonEnv), { production: false });`

Comment: I like more first variant. It has a benefit of clear syntax and allows to override only selected props. Pitty i didnt think of it earlier. Nice 1